# R not showing all columns anymore

Tags: r, rstudio

I recently updated RStudio to 2023.06.0 Build 421, but now the scroll function (see screenshot) does not work anymore.

[image: Column scroll functions]

My dataframe has 102 columns, but I only see 50 as I cannot scroll to the right. I already re-installed RStudio, did not solve the problem. I found a solution by using this code:

> rstudioapi::writeRStudioPreference("data_viewer_max_columns", 150L)

This solved my problem, but I just wanted to know if anyone else has this problem and if they were able to fix this.

Greetings
M

Comment: Instead of including your solution in your question, please post the question and your solution separately, re https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I understand your comment, but I just want to know if anyone else has this issue with R Studio and if there are ways to get these buttons working again.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with RStudio "Cherry Blossom" Release (3c53477a, 2023-03-09) for macOS, sorry. If I run this [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I get the navigation arrows and can view columns "4951:5000" using the ">>" button: `cols <- c(paste0("Column_", 1:5000)); samples <- paste0("Sample", 1:250); m <- matrix(sample(1:20, 1250000, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5000, nrow = 250, dimnames=list(samples, cols)); data <- as.data.frame(m); View(data)`.